# What does Caesar salad do if you leave it in the sun? (----)

Tags: wordplay, cipher, rhyme, poetry, humor

---

> What greeting to use with a bee when approaching its lair? (-)
>   What thing do relief sculptor DJs drop, pumping it too? (---)
>   What insect do little old ladies purl all through their hair? (----)
>   To keep the wheels going, now what does the kind engine do? (----)
>   What weapon would groundsmen make use of to fight if they care? (---)
>
> What language do mules talk in, off in that India place? (-----)
>   What does pastor Grey’s grass do if you make your Pa Strayan? Oh! (----)
>   What do Friday and Saturday get if they’re punched in the face? (-----)
>   Word for Bollywood throw(back) that in quite a high arc will go? (---)
>   What snack do the mathematicians all eat, with pastry? (--)
>   And if you put ‘er in a stage, what should Tina’s name be? (-----)
>
> Now tell me, pray tell, what hay chooses to look at a jay? (-)
>   The best dressed-up cat (with a suit) must be this, yes it must! (-----)
>   Now what’s each division (on Klingons' CDs) you can play? (----)
>   I don’t understand numbers that I cannot halve, for they’re just… (---)
>
> What’s it called if your barber, with no cue, just gives you a quiff? (--)
>   What did doctors prescribe when ‘e fainted at sight of a tee? (---)
>   And what is the sixth letter’s favourite conjunction (not and)? (--)
>   If you spin them around and around what will soft drinks then be? (-----)
>   What word might help Erica into the USA pass? (--)
>   Where does butt stick in honey, if not on the making bee’s arse? (---)
>
> Do you know which psychiatrist lived in the jungle all day? (----)
>   What do you call your dog’s cup if all you see in it is pee? (---)
>   If I asked you the name of your largest child what would you say? (---)
>   A word for autistic high-functioning snakes might well be… (---)
>   To make you feel listless and bored has this city a way. (--)
>
> (-------,------)

---

For a little bit of light fun, have some very bad (and Dad) jokes, excruciatingly punny or downright stupid, with an easy dash of decoding dressing to go all round!

---

**Hint**:

> The dashes are letter counts. Think lighthearted, punny and silly - these are mostly (very) bad jokes, *not* cryptic clues. Even though a question may seem to have more than one possible answer, discovering the crux of the puzzle should help you rule out most alternatives. Some of them are *very* obvious; feel free to post partial answers. Given the lighthearted nature of this, I'd presume the answer to the title is also obvious, and will help you solve the puzzle?

Comment: Are the dashes letter counts or something else?

Comment: I imagine that due to the title (CEASER cipher) as well as 'an easy dash of decoding' and the tag 'cipher' that some part involves a rotational cipher

Comment: @Mohirl See my hint for clarification

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Answer**

What greeting to use with a bee when approaching its lair? (-)

> A?

What thing do relief sculptor DJs drop, pumping it too? (---)

> Bas

What insect do little old ladies purl all through their hair? (----)

> Nits?

To keep the wheels going, now what does the kind engine do? (----)

What weapon would groundsmen make use of to fight if they care? (---)

What language do mules talk in, off in that India place? (-----)

> Hinny

What does pastor Grey’s grass do if you make your Pa Strayan? Oh! (----)

What do Friday and Saturday get if they’re punched in the face? (-----)

> Dazed

Word for Bollywood throw(back) that in quite a high arc will go? (---)

What snack do the mathematicians all eat, with pastry? (--)

> Pi

And if you put ‘er in a stage, what should Tina’s name be? (-----)

Now tell me, pray tell, what hay chooses to look at a jay? (-)

The best dressed-up cat (with a suit) must be this, yes it must! (-----)

Now what’s each division (on Klingons' CDs) you can play? (----)

> Trek

I don’t understand numbers that I cannot halve, for they’re just… (---)

> Odd

What’s it called if your barber, with no cue, just gives you a quiff? (--)

> If

What did doctors prescribe when ‘e fainted at sight of a tee? (---)

And what is the sixth letter’s favourite conjunction (not and)? (--)

> If

If you spin them around and around what will soft drinks then be? (-----)

> Dizzy?

What word might help Erica into the USA pass? (--)

> Am

Where does butt stick in honey, if not on the making bee’s arse? (---)

Do you know which psychiatrist lived in the jungle all day? (----)

> Jung

What do you call your dog’s cup if all you see in it is pee? (---)

If I asked you the name of your largest child what would you say? (---)

A word for autistic high-functioning snakes might well be… (---)

> Asp

To make you feel listless and bored has this city a way. (--)

Comment: +1 Nice work so far. There's 2 answers that are slightly incorrect (a spelling alternative related to the pun) but they should be able to be weeded out at a later step.